# How to project specific elements in an Array field in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this data in MongoDB:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c7e459f875ea5548de25722"),
"Autos" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9759e1c3895999adaceb"),
        "deleted" : 1,

    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9a8be1c3895999adacef"),
        "deleted" : 0,

    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9aa4e1c3895999adacf0"),
        "deleted" : 0,
    }
]
    }

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c7e45e9875ea5548de25724"),
"Shoemaking" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9770e1c3895999adacec"),
        "deleted" : 1,
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9a5de1c3895999adaced"),
        "deleted" : 0,
    },
]
```

I want to basically `select * from table where deleted = 0`
show where the deleted records are equal to 0.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
db.rental.find({"Autos.deleted":{$ne: 1}}).pretty()

db.rental.find({"Autos":  {$elemMatch: {deleted: 1 } } } ).pretty()

db.rental.find({"Autos.deleted": 0},{"Autos": {$elemMatch: 
{deleted:0}}});
```

But none of the above work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Desired output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7e459f875ea5548de25722"),
    "Autos" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9a8be1c3895999adacef"),
            "deleted" : 0,

        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9aa4e1c3895999adacf0"),
            "deleted" : 0,
        }
    ]
        }

        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5c7e45e9875ea5548de25724"),
          "Shoemaking" : [
              {
                  "_id" : ObjectId("5cad9a5de1c3895999adaced"),
                  "deleted" : 0,
              },
          ]
}
```

I want the output to be something like the above, but all the queries I have tried so far either select only one record of Array or select nothing at all.

Comment: You want to seperate records or the same format with no deleted?

Comment: @GursheeshSingh I want to find all records but not where deleted record=1 in sql it would be something like select * from table where deleted != 1. Thanks

Comment: @SaqyG Can you post the desired output?

Comment: @GursheeshSingh here I have updated the question with desired output thanks

Comment: You have to unwind the array and then use equal condition to get the records and then format the documents according to your wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.rental.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         Autos: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Autos",
               as: "auto",
               cond: { $eq:["$$auto.deleted",0] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Seeragh your answer is the closest now I can see the record with deleted 0 but it only shows the first record of the array not the second. It is more like select top 1 from table where deleted = 0. How to view all other records with deleted=0

Comment: @seeragh that was awesome it worked as expected. Thank you !! after all the answer it finally worked. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
db.rental.find({ "Autos.deleted": { $eq: 0 } } )
```

Comment: Hey Raja thanks for the reply I have already tried that it also gives me record which where deleted = 1

Answer (score 0):

use $elemMatch to match contain inside array. [mongodb-$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
db.rental.find({
      Autos: {
        $elemMatch: {
          deleted: 0
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Bipin for reply I tried your query its not filtering out delete=1 instead its just displaying whole Autos array same as @Raja sekar reply. Now as for as I think its either the problem with 0 and 1 approach or projection